# Verifying the signature of mpc protocol (ZenGo) on Ethereum

Tags: cryptography, ethereum, digital-signature, ecdsa

I am getting invalid signature while verifying the signature on Ethereum generated by mpc protocol (ZenGo). They are generating signature in the form of Secp256k1 scalar values but I am not able to verify this signature on Ethereum. The signature is given below:

```
{"r":{"curve":"secp256k1","scalar":[212,128,66,50,225,8,7,202,86,98,222,115,126,114,36,138,189,23,117,144,32,100,182,135,9,133,104,229,209,164,28,113]},"s":{"curve":"secp256k1","scalar":[1,202,42,200,58,18,70,41,217,251,25,64,25,194,198,116,167,149,32,176,13,191,215,33,109,58,149,40,7,235,80,11]},"recid":0}
```

public key: [2,251,21,234,208,237,227,184,164,83,66,18,133,70,125,132,249,62,145,186,65,123,150,213,161,192,94,86,25,120,245,130,248]

using these I'm trying to verify signature but getting invalid signature. So can anyone please help me out in this? I would appreciate in advance.

I have tried to verify signature generated from ZenGo mpc code on solidity but getting invalid signature.

Comment: Your code and the language tag are missing. Also, your data is incomplete, the message is missing (if you don't want to share this, post other *complete* test data).

Comment: Thanks Topaco, I'm generating signature using rust language of any message and trying to verify the transaction in solidity using ecrecover function but I am not able to verify the signature. because signature's r , s and public key values are in integer array format (Secp256k1 curve used) and I can't convert these into bytes32 form for verifying in solidity.

Comment: Your descriptions are just too vague. Please post first complete data, so that it is verifiable whether the signature is verifiable at all, and second a complete and executable code, so that a debugging is possible at all.